# C++ Efficient arithmetic operator overloading for class containing Eigen matrices

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, eigen

I want to construct a class that contains several Eigen Matrices or Vectors. I want the objects to behave as mathematical vectors: therefore I want to overload +, - and *(by a scalar). I want to do very many linear combinations of these objects, so I would like to implement it in a way that it takes full advantage of Eigen and creates as few copies and temporaries as possible.

I usually follow the recommendations in [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) but they require to pass some of the object by value rather than reference. Eigen "dislikes" when matrices are passed by value.

Below is my attempt (I overload only + for shortness) where I avoid passing by value in the overloading of + and instead I use the named return value optimization (NRVO):

```
template <int N> class myClass {
public:
   Eigen::Matrix<double, N, N> mat = Eigen::Matrix<double, N, N>::Zero();
   Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1> vec = Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1>::Zero();
public:
    myClass(){}
    myClass(Eigen::Matrix<double, N, N> & t_mat,Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1> &t_vec) : mat (t_mat), vec(t_vec){ }
    myClass(const myClass & other): mat(other.mat), vec(other.vec) {};
    myClass& operator+=(const myClass& rhs){
        mat += rhs.mat;      vec += rhs.vec;
        return *this;
    }

public:
        enum { NeedsToAlign = (sizeof(mat)%16)==0 || (sizeof(vec)%16)==0 };
        EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW_IF(NeedsToAlign)
};

template <int N> myClass<N>& operator+( const myClass<N>& lhs, const myClass<N>& rhs )
{
   myClass<N> nrv( lhs );
   nrv += rhs;
   return nrv;
}
```

Is this the best solution? Fastest?

As a final short question: it would be nice to use Boost/operators (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) to easily complete the set of operator overloading. Can I use that, or would that cause problems? I guess it will implement binary operations passing the first argument by value.

Comment: afaik eigen uses expression templates for arithmetics, then you either shouldnt interfere with that using your own operator overloading or you need something much more elaborated

Comment: for some pointers: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve the problem by myself. I tried several versions and compared them with directly summing Eigen vectors.

The first strategy follows [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading):

```
using realValueType = double;
const int NDim = 1000000;
using InternalVecType = Eigen::Matrix<realValueType, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>;

class MyVec {
public:
    InternalVecType vec;
    // ... Other properties
    
public:
    // Constructors
    MyVec(): vec(InternalVecType::Random(NDim,1)) {}    // Initialises as random, just for testing
    MyVec(const InternalVecType& other): vec(other) {};
    MyVec(const MyVec& other): vec(other.vec) {};       // Copy constructor
    MyVec(MyVec&& other){vec.swap(other.vec);}          // Move constructor
    
    // Arithmetic
    MyVec& operator=(MyVec other){vec.swap(other.vec);return *this;} // Copy-and-Swap
    MyVec& operator+=(const MyVec& other) {vec+=other.vec; return *this;}
    friend MyVec operator+(MyVec lhs, const MyVec& rhs) { lhs += rhs; return lhs;}
};
```

The second version uses NRVO

```
class MyVecNRVO {
public:
    InternalVecType vec;
    // ... Other properties
    
public:
    // Constructors
    MyVecNRVO(): vec(InternalVecType::Random(NDim,1)) {}    // Initialises as random, just for testing
    MyVecNRVO(const InternalVecType& other): vec(other) {};
    MyVecNRVO(const MyVec& other): vec(other.vec) {};       // Copy constructor
    MyVecNRVO(MyVec&& other){vec.swap(other.vec);}          // Move constructor
    
    // Arithmetic
    MyVecNRVO& operator=(MyVecNRVO other){vec.swap(other.vec);return *this;} // Copy-and-Swap
    MyVecNRVO& operator+=(const MyVecNRVO& other) {vec+=other.vec; return *this;}
    friend MyVecNRVO operator+(const MyVecNRVO& lhs, const MyVecNRVO& rhs) {
        MyVecNRVO nrv(lhs);  nrv += rhs; return nrv;}
};
```

My third version uses (probably clumsily) expression templates

```
struct Add { static InternalVecType apply(InternalVecType lhs, InternalVecType rhs) {return lhs+rhs;} };

template<class E1, class E2, class Op> struct ComplexExpr {
    E1 l_;
    E2 r_;
    ComplexExpr(E1 l, E2 r) : l_(l), r_(r) {}
    InternalVecType getvec(){return Op::apply(l_.getvec(), r_.getvec());}
};

template<class E1, class E2> ComplexExpr<E1, E2, Add> operator+ (E1 e1, E2 e2) {
    return ComplexExpr<E1, E2, Add>( e1, e2 );
}

class MyVecT {
public:
    InternalVecType vec;
    // ... Other properties

public:
    // Constructors
    MyVecT(): vec(InternalVecType::Random(NDim,1)) {}    // Initialises as random, just for testing
    MyVecT(const InternalVecType& other): vec(other) {};
//    template<> MyVecT(

    InternalVecType getvec(){return vec;};
};
```

To test it I created 15 vectors of types  `InternalVecType` (meaning the Eigen type not wrapped in my class), `MyVec`, `MyVecNRVO`, and `MyVecT` and summed them in a single line.

What I have noticed is that the first version is not only the fastest, but also as fast as directly adding the Eigen vectors in a single line! NRVO is around 5 times slower, while my attempt at expression templates 100 times slower (ouch! but in my defence, it is my very first attempt ever :D).

It seems that the first option is not only the best, but also the optimal. Maybe a better implementation of expression templates could achieve a better speed, but since the first option is as fast as the raw summation, it does not seem worth to go in that direction. Any comment is welcome.